Windows Defender SenseNdr.exe causing Non-Paged Pool memory leak after Windows Server update KB5041578
We're experiencing a significant Non-Paged Pool memory leak on our Windows Server 2019 domain controllers after installing the following updates:

KB5041578
Servicing Stack Update 10.0.17763.6174

Problem details:

The process SenseNdr.exe, part of Microsoft Defender for Endpoint, is causing a continuous increase in Non-Paged Pool memory usage.
This is affecting only Windows 2019 servers.
The memory leak is severe enough to impact server performance.

What we've tried:

Attempted to disable real-time protection via registry and group policy (unsuccessful).
Considered reinstalling Windows Defender (not possible due to management restrictions).
Investigated group policies and central management settings in Microsoft 365 Defender.

Questions:

Has anyone else encountered this specific memory leak with SenseNdr.exe after these updates?
Are there any known workarounds or fixes for this issue that don't involve completely disabling Microsoft Defender for Endpoint?
If disabling components is necessary, what's the safest way to do this on domain controllers without compromising security?
Has Microsoft acknowledged this as a bug in the recent updates?

Environment:

OS: Windows Server 2019
Latest Update: KB5043050
Servicing Stack: 10.0.17763.6174
Centrally managed via Microsoft 365 Defender/Intune

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. We're trying to resolve this without compromising our domain controllers' security posture.

Sensendr.exe is a component of Windows Defender ATP. When I offboard Windows Defender ATP, Sensendr.exe is no longer active. After this, I was able to remove and reinstall Windows Defender. However, upon onboarding Windows Defender ATP again, the problem reoccurs.

I haven't personally seen the issue, but found Any updates on KB5041578 (Server 2019 performance issue)? on reddit where other users have reported an issue. There are some suggested work-around on that reddit thread.
Servers might face performance issues with the August 2024 security update on the Microsoft site contains:

After installing the August 2024 Windows security update, released August 13, 2024 (KB5041578), you might observe that some Windows Server 2019 devices experience system slowdowns, unresponsiveness, and high CPU usage particularly with Cryptographic Services.
Resolution: This issue was resolved by Windows updates released September 10, 2024 (KB5043050), and later. We recommend you install the latest security update for your device as it contains important improvements and issue resolutions, including this one.

Therefore, suggest try to get KB5043050 installed rather than applying a different work-around.

I'm going to install the latest update. I hadn't done it yet because nothing was mentioned about memory issues.

KB5043050 has been installed but it did not resolve the issue. I'm seeing the NP pool for SenseNdr.exe increasing again.

@AnthonytenHerkel Thanks for the clarification that KB5043050 didn't resolve the issue. I'm not sure what to try next. Agree that the Microsoft article I found describes performance issues with KB5041578, but doesn't specifically mention the memory usage for SenseNdr.exe. Not sure if worth you editing the question to say installing KB5043050 didn't help, and I could then delete this "answer" as didn't help to fix the issue.
